# intersection of two arrays

Tags: c, array

I have written a logic to find out the intersection of two arrays. Please review my logic and guide me if my logical approach is not correct.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void intersect(int a1[][2], int a2[][2],int row, int col) 
{

 int i = 0, j= 0, x = 0, y = 0;

for(i = 0; i <row ; i++)
{
    for(j = 0 ; j < col ; j++)
    {
            for(x = 0; x < row ; x++)
            {
                for(y = 0; y < col ; y++)
                {
                    if(a1[i][j] == a2[x][y]) 
                        printf("%d\t",a1[i][j]);

                }
            }
    }
}
}

int main()
{
     int arr1[2][2]={{2,5},{6,8}};
     int arr2[2][2]={{1,2},{8,8}};
     int row = (sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]));
     int col = (sizeof(arr1[0])/sizeof(arr1[0][1]));
     intersect(arr1,arr2,row,col);
}
```

Comment: The complexity of your approach is quite significant. You can improve it by, for example, sorting the two arrays first

Comment: How did you compile that? `row` and `col` don't have a type in `main`.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ A "sorting the two arrays first " is not trivial in this case .  The array elements themselves are themselves arrays.  It is akin to sorting complex numbers and then matching either real,imaginary part.

Comment: @chux "sorting the two arrays first" is exactly trivial in this case. The code simply searches for *any* place where a value in `a1` appears in `a2`. Just convert the arrays to lists of numbers, sort them, and proceed.

Comment: @AustinHastings Fair enough.   I guess it becomes a question of how much space to replicate the array - or allow `intersect()` to modify in place.  As usual, more memory allows for faster search.

Comment: Should I sort them and place them in a single array and print out the duplicates?